# USB-C PD Source / Sink capable IC

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

Does anyone know of a combined source / sink IC for USB-C PD?

Ideally, one that is rather simple to configure, by holding configuration pins to ground or similar. This is not super necessary though.

At present i'm considering using the STUSB4500 for sink and STUSB4710A for source. A brief review indicates that this would require two USB-C ports. This seems a bit silly, as many devices are capable of providing both source and sink from a single port. Some of these devices are low cost and relatively small footprint, so there must be an IC that fits the bill.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Does anyone know ... ?` is a poll type question ... poll questions are off topic here

Comment: @jsotola get a grip mate.

Comment: Go to the website where you found your ST devices, they show a table for other chips with different features: https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/usb-type-c-and-power-delivery-controllers.html